# Error in mounted hook: "Error: An AuthUI instance already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, single-page-application, socialauth

I building a single page app using **Vuejs** and using Firebase for authentication. So far I got sign in and sign up to work with no problems. The issue I am having now is with **Social Authentication**.

When I load the sign up page the social buttons render, but when I navigate away and come back to sign up I get the following error:

**Error in mounted hook: "Error: An AuthUI instance already exists**

and the social buttons don't render anymore.

Here is my code:

```
mounted () {
  SocialAuth () {
    const uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/',
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ]
    }

    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
  }
}
```

Any help and all help with be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 16):

Did you try using `firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance()` like:

```
mounted () {
  SocialAuth () {
    const uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/',
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ]
    }

    if(firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance()) {
      const ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance()
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
    } else {
      const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aweseome! Thanks so much, that seems to have worked :)

Comment: Thanks this helped me get unblocked. The code can be simplified further into 2 lines.     
`const ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() ?? new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());`
`ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);`